# Problems with External List and Creating New Item with Webservice

Tags: web-services, error, external-content-type

can anybody verify that inserting new Items through SharePoint Webservice Method Lists.UpdateListItems is errornous?

I always get the Error:

*0x80070057Bad parameter passed to Web Server Extensions. Check the information you entered and try again.*

Answer (score 0):

The error in here is self explanatory you might given the web service method an incorrect parameter. UpdatelistItems method requires a batch parameter and the list name to make it work. it really is not that simple to create the batch parameter but for quick reference please find this [Link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/lists.lists.updatelistitems%28v=office.12%29.aspx)

Comment: Wrong. The real problem is that UpdateListItems is not supported via SOAP for external lists.